# Button text size changes on ViewPager Swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, textview, android-button

Problem:
The text in my buttons are displaying vertical after a page swipe in ViewPager.

Info:
I have a ViewPager that displays 4 different fragments.  One fragment contains 3 buttons at the top.  When the fragment initially loads, the buttons display correctly.  However when I swipe to a different fragment and back(2 swipes away), the text in the buttons are displayed vertical.  I'm guessing the size of the Button's TextView changed.  The other strange part, if I click any of the buttons the text in every button is displaying correctly.

Screenshot:

[image]

Attemped:

- invalidating the view during onPageSelected(int position) but no luck.
- Set the TextSize smaller, really small!
- called notifyDataSetChanged();

Devices:
Tested on android 4.2, 4.1 and 2.3.3 all with the same effect.

FragmentWithButtons XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tub_01"
        android:text="Map"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_selection"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/tub_02"
        android:text="List"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_selection"
        android:textSize="14sp"/> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/tub_03"
        android:text="Filter" 
        android:textColor="@color/tab_selection"
        android:textSize="14sp"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
    ...
```

Fragment With Buttons

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonFragment, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button1)
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return mainView;
}
```

PageAdapter

```
    public static class LocationPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public LocationPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return NUM_FRAGMENTS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int fragID) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Load fragment: " + fragID);
        switch(fragID){
        case 3: return new Fragment1();
        case 1: return new Fragment2();
        case 0: return new Fragment3();
        default: return new FragmentWithButtons();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    }
}
```

Any idea what is happening or how to solve it?

Comment: can you share FragmentWithButton's layout too? and maybe even main layout with ViewPager.

Comment: Added XML for FragmentWithButton's

Comment: It looks good. I would still try to replace RelativeLayout with LinearLayout/orientation=horizontal.